# Angular 2 databinding in the object

Tags: loops, angular, angular2-template

When you loop through the object , is there a way I can dynamically put angular handlers inside angular handlers?

- Array 'editor' with list of items.
- It has 4 top level items with id ( 1,2,3)
- It has 2 sub items i the children under ID 1 with id (4,5).

I am able to loop through the items and display.

In first item with id 1, it has number (4,5) - These are ID's from the main editor array. So instead of rendering a string that is 4 and 5 I would like to render the object from editor with ID 4 and Object with ID 5.

If I do {{editor[0].id}} - it works, but the [0] is not dynamic. So I tried 
{{editor[{{subitem}}].id}} - but that give me an error.

Here is HTML

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of editor">
        {{item.id}}
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let subitem of item.children">
                {{subitem}}
                {{editor[0].id}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Angular 2 component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'editor',
  templateUrl: './editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./editor.component.css']
})

export class EditorComponent implements OnInit {

      editor = {};
      constructor() {
        this.editor = editor;
         console.log('editor is', this.editor[1].item);
      }


      ngOnInit() {
      }

}

    const editor = [
        {
         id: 1, 
         item: 'pen',
         menuView: 'edit-view',
         mainView: 'edit-view',
         children:[4 , 5]
        },
        {id: 2, item: 'ruller', menuView: 'edit-view',mainView: 'edit-view'},
        {id: 3, item: 'pencil', menuView: 'pencil-view',mainView: 'pencil-view'},
        {id: 4, item: 'black', menuView: 'pen-black',mainView: 'pen--black'},
        {id: 5, item: 'white', menuView: 'pen-white',mainView: 'pen-white'},
 {id: 6, item: 'edit', menuView: 'edit-white',mainView: 'edit-white'},
 {id: 7, item: 'edit', menuView: 'edit-white',mainView: 'edit-white'}
    ];
```

How to show in the first loop only element with ID 1, 6,7 ?
Do I create a custom pipe? If I got an array of 1000 id is a pipe the best thing?

Comment: are you there? Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<li *ngFor="let item of editor">
        {{item.id}}
        <ul *ngIf="item.children">
            <li *ngFor="let subitem of item.children">
            {{getChild(subitem) | json}}

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

You should have the below method

```
getChild(id){
    console.log(_.find(this.editor, { 'id': id}));
    return _.find(this.editor, { 'id': id});
  }
```

Note: I am using lodash library because I love it. 
**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/pJRN8oToOQSDFrNYLEmD?p=preview)**

Comment: @yurzui friends?? are you there in fb?

Comment: There is one issue with this solution:). Angular will call `getChild` function on every tick

Comment: @yurzui I did not understand, elaborate

Comment: Compare my https://plnkr.co/edit/6wF55OPbv4MbrZnGgeDi?p=preview with your plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/9jvrg0W7Rax3zvslNyZU?p=preview Just move mouse and observe browser console

Comment: I dont see any differences.

Answer (score 2):

As your object is actually array of objects you can use custom pipe to filter array:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'findById'
})
export class FindByIdPipe {
  transform(arr: any[], id: number) {
    return arr.find(x => x.id === id);
  }
}
```

then in your template

```
{{ (editor | findById: subitem).item }}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/qblGs5Gzkj3cnZWRmVIS?p=preview)**

Comment: Hi Yurzui, your plunker is empty .:(

Comment: Thank you for that, would you recommend to use pipe always?
For example I  would like to show in the First top level only certain ID elements. Should I use a pip to filter it? If my array grows into 100's of lines of records, will that now slow down the page as it filter through the whole list, if Just need to show in the top level id 1, 10 and 20  for example?

Comment: I would prepare data for view as soon as it has changed. Pipe is not always good idea especially for big data

Comment: What did you mean by that? So for the first level just hard code the ID that need to be shown at starting level? If so how do loop only certain ID's ? I tried    <li *ngFor="let item[1] of editor">

Comment: I am updated my question, to ask about the top level id's also. As I am not really clear about the pip aproach and what should I use alternative

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood but... You have to use the index. Look for "Local Variables" in [this page](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html)

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of editor; let editorIndex = index">
        {{item.id}}
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let subitem of item.children">
                {{subitem}}
                {{editor[editorIndex].id}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Or you can just use `item`:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of editor">
        {{item.id}}
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let subitem of item.children">
                {{subitem}}
                {{item.id}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```